# Spring NullPointerException service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts2, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to setup a small web application using Spring 3 Struts 2 and Hibernate but i'm doing something wrong i cant figure out what it's , when i try to call the service layer in the struts controller i get a NullPointerException.

entity :

```
@Entity(name="T_Personne")
public class Personne {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false,length=30)
    private String nom;
}
```

Dao :

```
@Repository(value="personneDao")
public class PersonneDaoImpl implements IPersonneDao{


    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.em = entityManager;
    }


    public void save(Personne per) {

        em.persist(per);
    }
}
```

Service :

```
@Service(value="personneService")
@Transactional
public class PersonneServiceImpl implements IPersonneService {

    @Autowired
    private IPersonneDao personneDao;

    public void savePersonne(Personne per) {
        personneDao.save(per);

    }

}
```

controller :

```
public class HelloAction extends ActionSupport{

    @Autowired
    private IPersonneService personneService;


    public String execute() throws Exception{

            Personne p = personneService.findPersonneById(1L);
            System.out.println("Nom : "+ p.getNom() + "Prenom : "+ p.getPrenom());

        return SUCCESS;

    } 
}
```

Spring XML :

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="net.cadr" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyPersistenceUnit"/>
    </bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Struts XML :

```
<struts>  

    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="personne" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="Hello" class="net.cadr.actions.HelloAction">
            <result name="success">/views/hello.html</result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

the thing is the entity manager create the tables  also the struts controller is working i can map actions and call them !!!

what i'm missing ?

Thank you

Comment: Where exactly do you get the `NPE`?

Comment: Your Personne Service does not have a `findPersonneById` method. Are you sure that the code compiles, or do you did not post the correct code?

Comment: hi ,i get the exception in this line   Personne p = personneService.findPersonneById(1L); thanks

Comment: which one is line 18?

Comment: hi , line 18 is :  Personne p = personneService.findPersonneById(1L);

Comment: Consider Spring managed beans vs Struts managed objects.

Comment: Struts is wiring by name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your controller is likely no spring bean (Spring does not uses Struts by default, instead it uses its own framework: Spring-MVC).

If you use Spring with Struts, then you should add this line to your struts configuration:

```
<constant name="struts.objectFactory"
          value="org.apache.struts2.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory" />
```

@See [Struts Spring Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/spring-plugin.html)

Comment: As from 2.3.x just drop in the plugin
http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/spring-plugin.html

Comment: @LukaszLenart: do you mean it is not needed? from the reference (yellow box) "But, if you want to use Spring to inject your Actions, the option is there."

Comment: It means, you don't have to define each action in Spring configuration. And:
`To enable Spring integration, simply include struts2-spring-plugin-x-x-x.jar in your application.

If you are using more than one object factory, (for example, by including both the Spring and Plexus plugins in your application,) you will need to set the struts.objectFactory property in struts.properties or in one of several XML files via Constant`